pushforward measure and uniform distribution
Let $m,d$ be an integer. Let $\mathcal{X}=\{1,\dots,m\}$ be the set of integers between $1$ and $m$. Let $\mathcal{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ be a subset of $d$-dimensional euclidean space and $\mathcal{H} = \{h: \mathcal{Z} \to \mathcal{X}\}$ be a set of functions.
Question
I am looking for a general characterization of $(\mathrm{D},\mathcal{H})$ such that the following holds: Let $Z \sim \mathrm{D}$ where $\mathrm{D}$ is a distribution over $\mathcal{Z}$. Then, there exists $h \in \mathcal{H}$ such that the distribution of $h(Z)$ is $\mathrm{Unif}(\mathcal{X})$, i.e., uniform distribution over $\mathcal{X}$.

I'm not sure if there is a difference between $H$ and $\mathcal{H}$ in the question, I assume here that there is no difference. Given a random element $Z$ that takes values over a general measurable space $(V, \mathcal{G})$, a measurable $h:V\rightarrow{1, ..., m}$ exists so that $h(Z)$ is uniform over ${1, ..., m}$ if and only if there are disjoint measurable sets $A_1, ..., A_m$ (so $A_i\in \mathcal{G}$ for all $i$) such that $P[Z\in A_i]=1/m$ for $i\in{1, ..., m}$.

thanks. Fixed the typo there. hmm. it is a general enough characterization.

Fix $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ as a probability space. Let $(V,\mathcal{G})$ be another measurable space. Let $Z:\Omega\rightarrow V$ be measurable (with respect to input space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ and output space $(V,\mathcal{G})$). Fix $m$ as a positive integer.
Claim 1: There is a measurable function $h:V\rightarrow \{1, ..., m\}$ such that $h(Z)$ is distributed uniformly over $\{1, ..., m\}$ if and only if there are disjoint sets $A_1, ..., A_m$ that are measurable subsets of $V$ such that $P[Z\in A_i]=1/m$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., m\}$.
Claim 2: If there is a measurable map $\phi:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that random variable $\phi(Z)$ has a continuous cumulative distribution function, then there is a measurable $h:V\rightarrow\{1, ..., m\}$ such that $h(Z)$ is distributed uniformly over $\{1, ..., m\}$.
Proof of Claim 1: Suppose a measurable $h:V\rightarrow\{1, ..., m\}$ exists such that $h(Z)$ is uniform over $\{1, ..., m\}$. Define $A_i=h^{-1}(i)$ for $i \in \{1, ..., m\}$. Then $A_1, ..., A_m$ are disjoint measurable subsets of $V$ and $P[A_i] = P[h(Z)=i]=1/m$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., m\}$.
Conversely, suppose $A_1, ..., A_m$ are disjoint measurable subsets of $V$ that satisfy $P[Z\in A_i]=1/m$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., m\}$. Define the measurable function $h:V\rightarrow\{1, ..., m\}$ by
$$h(z) = 1_{\{z \notin \cup_{i=2}^mA_i\}} + \sum_{i=2}^m i1_{\{z \in A_i\}} \quad \forall z \in V$$
Then for each $i \in \{2, .., m\}$ we have $P[h(Z)=i]=P[Z \in A_i]=1/m$.  It follows that
$$P[h(Z)=1]=1-\sum_{i=2}^mP[h(Z)=i]=1/m$$
$\Box$
Proof of Claim 2: Define $X=\phi(Z)$. Since $X$ has a continuous CDF $F_X(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there are disjoint intervals $I_1, ..., I_m\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $\cup_{i=1}^m I_i=\mathbb{R}$ and
$$ P[X \in I_i]=1/m \quad \forall i \in \{1, ..., m\}$$
Define the measurable function $h:V\rightarrow\{1, ..., m\}$ by
$$ h(z) = \sum_{i=1}^m i 1_{\{\phi(z) \in I_i\}} \quad \forall z \in V$$
Then for each $i \in \{1, ..., m\}$ we have
$$P[h(Z)=i]=P[\phi(Z)\in I_i]=P[X\in I_i]=1/m$$
$\Box$
